# Xamarin Forms Bot error 404

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm developing a simple chat interface similar to the Bot Emulator in Xamarin that communicates with a chatbot deployed in my localhost IIS server. I'm using as base for my work [this](https://github.com/bozd4g/LuisAI-XamarinForms) project. The Android APP can establish a connection with the server and the messages are correctly sent to the IIS server, but when I get the response from the server in the Bot Emulator console which I use as debug during communications I receive an error like this:

```
  {
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2018-01-04T18:46:42.7490251Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2018-01-04T18:46:42.7490251+00:00",
  "serviceUrl": "https://*******.ngrok.io",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "21dg57hma959"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
  "membersAdded": [],
  "membersRemoved": [],
  "locale": "en-US",
  "text": "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "8idhmm3flgbi",
  "id": null
}
```

With description: Conversation not found. I don't know what's wrong with the code because I don't get errors in Visual studio. Any help will be appreciated :)

PS: In the Xamarin I receive a correct response from the server, but It's like every message establish a new connection because I can't go on with a dialog.

Comment: How do you test your bot? Where did you deploy your xamarin.forms android app? Where did you deploy your bot application?

Comment: What version of the Microsoft.Bot.Builder sdk are you using?  The bot in the solution you referenced is on v3.8 ... please try updating this to the latest.